# Precalculus - Exponential and Logarithmic Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Mike Kallenberg deposited some money in a bank account that earns 5.6% interest compounded continuously.  How long would it take to double the amount in money in Mr. Kallenberg's account?

Comment: Hello.  What are your thoughts on the problem at hand?  WHat have you learned regarding continuously compounding interest?

Comment: I was thinking it would be 2P = Pe^0.056t, but I don't know where to go from there. We haven't really learned much besides the formula itself and how to solve using logs and natural logs.

Comment: You are on the right track.  2P is double your principal and e^.056t represents the interest over time, t.  So now you must solve for t.  So have you learned how to solve for variables that are exponents?

Comment: Yes, by using logs. So log(2P) = 0.056Ptloge ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$2P=Pe^{.056t}$$
Dividing by P gets me
$$2=e^{.056t}$$
Now to undo the exponent, you take the natural log, ln, of each side...
$$\ln{2}=\ln{e^{.056t}}=.056t$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: so the answer is t = 12.38 ?

Comment: Yes...it will take approximately 12.4 years for Mr. Kallenberg's original principal to double under continuously compounding interest at 5.6%.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was much easier than I thought.